# vscode activating extension failed: Cannot find module with non-relative import

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am working on a Visual Studio Code extension, where I am using non-relative imports in typescript, for example:

```
import ModuleA from 'modules/ModuleA';
```

Where the actual folder to `ModuleA` is `src/modules/ModuleA` and the `tsconfig.json` is as follows, where I specify `src` as the `baseUrl`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "outDir": "out",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "lib": [
      "es6"
    ],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    ".vscode-test"
  ]
}
```

Everything compiles and builds just fine, however, when I attempt to launch the extension for testing, I get the error: `Activating extension failed: Cannot find module 'modules/ModuleA'`. My `.vscode/launch.json` file that I use to launch the extension looks like this:

```
// A launch configuration that compiles the extension and then opens it inside a new window
{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch Extension",
      "type": "extensionHost",
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}",
      "args": ["--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceRoot}" ],
      "stopOnEntry": false,
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "outFiles": ["${workspaceRoot}/out"],
      "preLaunchTask": "build",
      "internalConsoleOptions" : "openOnSessionStart"
  }
  ]
}
```

How do I get non-relative paths working for developing vscode extensions?

Comment: Why do you want to do "non-relative"? You probably should not use `baseUrl` for this. Try reference it directly using relative path: `./module/ModuleA` (assuming your code is under `src`

Answer (score 2):

For me the solution was to do an npm compile, which I did by doing a `Run Build Task` from the command palette (cmd+shift+p), then selecting `npm compile - <extension name>`. I believe you can also accomplish this from the terminal in your project directory with `tsc -p ./`

Comment: This solved it for me, as well: **Terminal > Run Build Task...** and then `tsc -p ./`

Comment: This works, on the default vscode project you can run `npm run compile` from the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar experience, I reinstall the node, the same version, and the problem was solved.

I am using Mac, so:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
brew reinstall node
```

Reference: [Error: Cannot find module '../lib/utils/unsupported.js' while using Ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44363066/error-cannot-find-module-lib-utils-unsupported-js-while-using-ionic)

Comment: I tested this on windows with `nvm install lts` but my error remains. Can you add some detail of the process of reinstallation?

Comment: @Pablion, the above is for linux and macos, also it has been a while, would you mind to explain a little more about what kind of issue you have now?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm having the same error: `Activating extension 'X' failed: Cannot find module 'non/relative/path'
Require stack: ...` Yet my tsconfig and launch.json was the same. It is said that tsconfig doesnt change anything of the bundling process [here in the official repo](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/issues/4906#issuecomment-955023025).