# Error: Cannot find module '../lib/utils/unsupported.js' while using Ionic

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, ionic2

I always get this error message when I run "Ionic start project name":

#### Error message

```
Running command - failed![ERROR] An error occurred while running npm install (exit code 1):

    module.js:471
        throw err;
        ^

    Error: Cannot find module '../lib/utils/unsupported.js'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
        at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
        at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:19:21
        at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:79:3)
        at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
```

Comment: The relative path is wrong..

Comment: check the path in ./bash_profile

Comment: On MacOS - reinstall from  http://nodejs.org  helps see the upvotes of https://stackoverflow.com/a/12313655/1497139

Comment: If you have configured build script try "npm run build" and then "npm start"

Answer (score 843, accepted):

Try to remove `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm` and reinstall node again. This should work.

#### On MacOS with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/):

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
brew reinstall node
```

Comment: if anyone wants to get there via finder: https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/smoke/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/How-to-view-hidden-system-folders-in-Mac-OS-X-s.html

Comment: If you are using brew then you can use: `brew unistall --force node` and `brew install node`

Comment: @Nico the first command has a typo. The correction will be `brew uninstall --force node`.

Comment: why it's happening?

Comment: After executing the above commands, now getting >> -bash: /usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory

Comment: In my case just had to do a `yarn cache clean` (likely from upgrading from 1.9 to 1.14).

Comment: Mac OS Mojave, brew installed under prior Mac OSX. I had issues installing node relating to permissions with instruction to run "brew postinstall node" to resolve failures. Once installed version of npm was older and npx not installed / not in bin. I used "brew doctor" to fix issues with the system, then "brew upgrade". Then ran the above to reinstall node.

Comment: @rmpt, same issue as you now T.T

Comment: Might need to run sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*

Comment: Having this issue in Windows PC as well . Any solution for that

Answer (score 85):

I followed the previous answers and reinstalled node. But I got this error.

> Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully You can
>   try again using `brew postinstall node`

So I ran this command

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local/lib/node_modules/
```

Then ran

```
brew postinstall node
```

Comment: alternatively you could run sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*

Answer (score 28):

I received a similar error and now have it working.

First make sure you have the latest version

```
brew update
```

Remove your previous instance of node:

```
brew uninstall node
```

Then reinstall the latest version:

```
brew install node
```

And then make sure it is symlinked into /usr/local if it isn't already. You would get an error to let you know to complete this step.

```
brew link --overwrite node
```

More details on how to install/upgrade node [are also available](https://treehouse.github.io/installation-guides/mac/node-mac.html).

Comment: You can use `brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies node` if, for example, you have `yarn` in your system.

Answer (score 19):

On Mac OS X (10.12.6), I resolved this issue by doing the following:

```
brew uninstall --force node
brew install node
```

I then got an error complaining that node postinstall failed, and to rerun `brew postinstall node`

I then got an error:

```
permission denied @ rb_sysopen /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx
```

I resolved that error by:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

And now I don't get this error any more.

Comment: I had to repeat this a few times, on different folders that either needed to be created or needed to have their ownership changed (to my user). Each time I would run `brew postinstall node` to find the next problem, fix that, repeat.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using "n" library @ https://github.com/tj/n . Do the following

```
  echo $NODE_PATH
```

If node path is empty, then

```
sudo n latest    - sudo is optional depending on your system
```

After switching Node.js versions using n, npm may not work properly.

```
curl -0 -L https://npmjs.com/install.sh | sudo sh
echo NODE_PATH
```

You should see your Node Path now. Else, it might be something else

Answer (score 10):

The error `Cannot find module '../lib/utils/unsupported.js'` is caused by `require('../lib/utils/unsupported.js')` in `./lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js`.

According to [the nodejs `require` docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_require_id), the required module is searched relative to the file, as it starts with `../`.

Thus, if we take the relative path `../lib/utils/unsupported.js` starting from `./lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js`, the required module must reside in `./lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js`. If it is not there, I see two options:

- the installation is corrupt, in which case [Vincent Ducastel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45348862/3568069) to reinstall node might work
- `npm` is no symlink to `./lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js`. This is what caused the error in my setup. If you call `npm`, it will typically find it be searching it in the directories listed in the `PATH` env var. It might for example be located in `./bin`. However, `npm` in a `./bin` directory should only be a symlink to the aforementioned `./lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js`. If it is not a symlink but directly contains the code, somewhere in the installation process the symlink got replaced by the file it links to. In this case, it should be sufficient to recreate the symlink: `cd ./bin; rm npm; ln -s ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js npm` (update: command fixed, thx @massimo)

All answers that suggest to check the `NODE_PATH` or the `npmrc` config should be ignored, as these are not considered when searching modules relatively.

Comment: I had similar issue with the wrong/missing symlink, but actually the syntax to recreate is: `ln -s ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js npm`

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned earlier.

```
 sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
 brew uninstall --force node                
 brew install node
```

Answer (score 7):

Tried all above/older brew installation answers, none is working for my laptop.

Only below method could fix my issue.

1) Run following commands:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
brew uninstall --force node
```

2) Then, proceed to Node.js Official Website https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/ to download latest package for new installation.

3) Run your npm command again, which should longer have any errors.

This method is working on **macOS Mojave Version 10.14.4**.

Answer (score 5):

https://nodejs.org/en/

Simply download node from the official website, this worked for me! :)

Comment: I tried almost everything else posted here and this is what fixed it for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

On Windows:

Remove the npm folder in  ~/AppData/Roaming

Comment: I only had to delete the sub folder npm cache in that directory.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you should re-install node:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
 brew uninstall --force node                
 brew install node
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply follow three steps;

1. Clear `npm` cache forcefully:

   `npm cache clean -f`
2. Install `n` package globally using `npm`:

   `npm install -g n`
3. Install from any of three options:

   a. `sudo n stable (get the stable version)`

   b. `sudo n latest (get the latest version of node)`

   c. `sudo n x.x.x (get the specific version of node)`

Answer (score 1):

I got this error by mixing install/update methods:  installed node via downloading package from website  and later I used brew to update.

I fixed by uninstalling the brew version :

> brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies node

Then I went back to node website and downloaded and installed via the package manager: https://nodejs.org/en/download/
  For some reason, no amount of trying to reinstall via brew worked.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into a similar issue where the whole `../lib/utils` directory couldn't be found when I tried executing Mocha via `npm test`. I tried the mentioned solutions here with no luck. Ultimately I ended up uninstalling and reinstalling the Mocha package **that was a dependency in the npm project** I was working in and it worked after that. So if anyone's having this issue with an npm package installed as a dependency, try uninstalling and reinstalling the package if you haven't already!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by running below command

`nvm install node --reinstall-packages-from=node`

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was $NODE_PATH missing:

```
NODE="/home/ubuntu/local/node" #here your user account after home
NODE_PATH="/usr/local/lib/node_modules" 
PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:$NODE/bin:$NODE/lib/node_modules"
```

To check just `echo $NODE_PATH` empty means it is not set. Add them to .bashrc is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

On fedora 27 I solved the problem by doing this:

```
sudo rm -f  /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
sudo dnf reinstall nodejs
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a helpful video and [blog post](https://codewithintent.com/how-to-completely-remove-node-js-in-osx/) about removing node from your computer OS. It is a different method of removal based on how you installed node in the first place (brew vs. binary file downloaded from https://nodejs.org/en/

- if you installed node with Homebrew then brew uninstall node will work. Verify that with running a `node -v` command in your terminal.
- Otherwise and if you have installed the binary file from [nodeJS's website](https://nodejs.org/en/)then you have to run this command in your terminal: `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/{bin/{node,npm},lib/node_modules/npm,lib/node,share/man/*/node.*}`. Again, verify that with running a node -v command.
- In both cases, successful removal of node should result in bash not recognizing what node is if it is completely removed

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome to *support* an answer, but the answer you post should be completely self-contained, i.e. not require visitors to click through to another site which may contain unexpected or malicious content, or no longer exist at all.

Answer (score 0):

In my macOS (10.13.3), I got it solved after reinstalling [Node version manager](https://github.com/creationix/nvm).

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash
source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

This may happen when the `npm/lib` folder got emptied for some reason (could also happen due to permission issues in the last usage).

A reinstallation of the node could solve the issue (as stated on other answers here), but I would suggest using a wonderful tool called `nvm` (Node Version Manager), which is able to manage multiple version of `node` and `npm` - this is mostly useful on dev machines with more than one projects require different versions of node.

When you [install nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm), this message will go away and you will have the latest version of `node` and `npm` to use.

In order to see the list of currently installed node versions in your nvm, just run:

```
nvm list
```

In order to install and use a new node version, run:

```
nvm install <node_version>
```

For example to install latest version of node 10.x, run:

```
nvm install 10
```

In order to switch to currently installed version, run:

```
nvm use <node_version>
```

In order to switch to system's original node version, just run:

```
nvm use system
```

Hope this helps.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue by removing node_modules and then reinstall node stable version.

Comment: Please add why this solves the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can run this command it will automatically remove the previous version of npm and install new version for details https://github.com/npm/cli

```
curl -qL https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh
```