# VS code extension "HelloWorld" sample in typescript is not working

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to create VS code extension and followed the steps provided in documentation [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/example-hello-world)

I setup "helloworld" project in typescript but when i press "F5", nothing happening. I saw, typescript files complied to JS but project is not opening new instance of VS code and enable debug mode not enabled on "F5".

Any suggestions ?.

launch.json file

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Extension",
        "type": "extensionHost",
        "request": "launch",
        "runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}",
        "args": [
            "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}"
        ],
        "outFiles": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/out/**/*.js"
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "npm: watch"
    },
    {
        "name": "Extension Tests",
        "type": "extensionHost",
        "request": "launch",
        "runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}",
        "args": [
            "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}",
            "--extensionTestsPath=${workspaceFolder}/out/test"
        ],
        "outFiles": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/out/test/**/*.js"
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "npm: watch"
    },

]
```

}

Steps i followed is same as mentioned in VS code doc

1. npm install -g yo generator-code
2. yo code
3. Launch VS Code,
4. choose File > Open Folder and pick the folder that you generated.
5. Press F5 or click on the Debug icon and click Start.

   For me step #5 is not working and not doing anything

Comment: is there a launch.json file created?

Comment: Yes, it created launch.json file and i'm seeing task in debug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your launch file doesn't look like the one generated  by `yo 2.0.2`.
That one generates a launch file version 0.1.0 rather than 0.2.0 like yours.

Currently you should have yo 2.0.2 and vscode 1.24.0. Please verify.

I created a typescript extension for vscode from the ground up and get this:

```
{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch Extension",
        "type": "extensionHost",
        "request": "launch",
        "runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}",
        "args": ["--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceRoot}" ],
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/out/src",
        "preLaunchTask": "npm"
    },
    {
        "name": "Launch Tests",
        "type": "extensionHost",
        "request": "launch",
        "runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}",
        "args": ["--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceRoot}", "--extensionTestsPath=${workspaceRoot}/out/test" ],
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/out/test",
        "preLaunchTask": "npm"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I was in VS code 1.23.1 and yo 2.0.2. After upgrading to VS code to 1.24.0, its working fine.

Answer (score 18):

I have the same issue in my VSCode version 1.72

and in package.json it was the latest at generation time (1.74)

check the VSCode version in package.json

```
"engines": {
   "vscode": "^1.52.0"
  },
```

use your version or less than your version

EX:- my VSCode version is 1.72 and added 1.52

Answer (score 6):

For me I check my vs code version

```
▶ code --version 
1.75.1
441438abd1ac652551dbe4d408dfcec8a499b8bf
x64
```

Update it in
package.json

```
  "vscode": "^1.75.1"
```

Hope it can help you :}}

Answer (score 4):

In my case it was the VSCode version, i updated to the latest and it worked

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I just reinstall the node, the same version, the problem solved.

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
brew reinstall node
```

Reference: [Error: Cannot find module '../lib/utils/unsupported.js' while using Ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44363066/error-cannot-find-module-lib-utils-unsupported-js-while-using-ionic)

Answer (score 0):

In case you are trying to open it in a monorepo, open the extension in its own instance of vscode and then tap F5.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was having WSL as the default profile for the terminal.

Comment: Can you add a little context as to why this causes the problem?

Comment: My guess is that vscode extensions require the windows file system. I.E. you can't search for C:\Users on wsl