# Unable to access npm

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install

I installed `node`(which internally installs `npm`) offline following instructions from [here](https://medium.com/@rabbi.cse.sust.bd/install-nodejs-via-binary-archive-on-ubuntu-18-04-63118473d9e9)

Node is returned -

```
$ node -v
v10.22.0
```

But npm failed -

```
$ npm --version
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../lib/utils/unsupported.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at /opt/node-v10.22.0-linux-x64/bin/npm:19:21
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/node-v10.22.0-linux-x64/bin/npm:155:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
```

Could you help to understand how to resolve this?

I tried solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/45348862/1471417 but no luck.

Comment: uninstall nodejs and install again, btw latest is 12.18.4

Answer (score 0):

will this help ?

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nodejs

export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Comment: How do you know OP uses Linux?

Comment: @MichaelSchnerring The link in the last paragraph of the question is specific to Ubuntu.

Comment: @MichaelSchnerring check its error code you will find it

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are on linux, please try this :

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

or you can try to reinstall npm with npm if this part of npm is not broken :

```
npm i -g npm
```