# npm package getting installed but not working

Tags: node.js, npm, ubuntu-18.04, lerna

when I am using command `npm install -g lerna` it gets executed with no error but after that using command
`lerna --version` gives output "lerna:command not found".
**Possible solution**
maybe if somehow I manage it to install in `usr/local/lib/node_modules` it should work cause other npm packages installed here are working fine but its getting installed in `/home/surajkulriya/.npm-global/lib/node_modules`.

OS: ubuntu 18.04

```
which npm:/usr/local/bin/npm
which node:/usr/local/bin/node
which nodejs:/usr/bin/nodejs
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63940148/13126651 this will solve your problem,just export path variable.Did it help?

Comment: @JatinMehrotra no bro i tried tried the above thing and reinstalled it again and got the same error gain

Answer (score 0):

Finally after too much effort I sorted out the issue. I removed node nodejs and npm completely and reinstalled them again and used command

```
npm i -g npm
```

to fix the broken dependecies.I reinstalled lerna and it worked.